# Averaging multivariate normal distributions, extend covariance along a vector

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, probability

If I have two separate multivariate normal random variables:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np

cov0=np.array([
    [1,0,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,1]
])
mean0 = np.array([1,1,1])
rv3d_0 = multivariate_normal(mean=mean0, cov=cov0)

cov1=np.array([
    [1,0,0],
    [0,1,0],
    [0,0,1]
])
mean1 = np.array([4,4,4])
rv3d_1 = multivariate_normal(mean=mean1, cov=cov1)
```

Then I am interested in creating a new random variable that is between these two:

```
mean_avg = (mean0+mean1)/2
cov_avg = (cov0+cov1)/2
rv3d_avg = multivariate_normal(mean=mean_avg, cov=cov_avg)

# I can then plot the points generated by:
rv3d_0.rvs(1000)
rv3d_1.rvs(1000)
rv3d_avg.rvs(1000)
```

However when looking at the points generated, the covariance is predictably the same as the two components. However what I would like is for the covariance to be greater along the vector (mean1-mean0) compared to the covariance along the orthogonal vectors. I think maybe taking the average of the covariance is not the proper technique? Any suggestions welcome, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by saying in between these two? When you average two identity matrices you again get identity matrix. Just take 2D example and try to manually find the covariance that does what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. Look at it this way: you have some specific directions for the covariance components, namely mean1 - mean0 is one direction and the plane orthogonal to mean1 - mean0 contains the others. In these directions you want to specify the magnitude of the variation, namely it's something (let's say FOO) in the orthogonal plane and a lot more (let's say 100 times FOO) in the direction mean1 - mean0.

You can find a basis for the orthogonal plane via the Gram-Schmidt algorithm or something. At this point you can construct a covariance matrix: let S = columns of the directions you've found (namely mean1 - mean plus the basis of the orthogonal plane), and let D = diagonal matrix with 100 FOO, FOO, FOO, ..., FOO on the diagonal. Now S D S^T (where S^T is the matrix transpose) is a positive definite matrix with the desired properties.

You might be able to avoid Gram-Schmidt, but your goal would be the same in any case: specify the properties you want and then construct a matrix to satisfy them.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following approach:

1- sample a good amount of observations (say 10000) from both distributions: `obs0` and `obs1`

2- create a new array of observations `obs_avg` which is the sum of `obs0` and `obs1` divided by 2

3- for the obtained array, calculate the mean and the covariance. the code should look like this:

```
import numpy as np
obs0 = np.random.normal(mean0, np.sqrt(cov0), 10000) #sampling from a normal distribution
obs1 = np.random.normal(mean1, np.sqrt(cov1), 10000)
obs_avg = (obs0 + obs1)/2
mean_avg = np.mean(obs_avg, axis=0)
cov_avg = np.cov(obs_avg.T)
```

It's an experimental way of generating the mean and covariance of the average distribution, and I think it should give you pretty accurate results if you take a large enough number of observations.